# Auto Scroll Horizontal Mui TabList on Drag with react-beautiful-dnd

Tags: reactjs, scroll, material-ui, drag-and-drop, react-beautiful-dnd

I have tried to implement Drag & Drop feature in Mui TabList using [react-beautiful-dnd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-beautiful-dnd). The dnd is working fine but, I am facing an issue making horizontal list of tabs auto scroll while dragging when there are too many tabs to fit in the screen and the `variant` prop of Mui `TabList` is `scrollable`. See this codesandbox example - https://codesandbox.io/s/draggable-and-scrollable-mui-tabs-xqgl77. This seems like a standard use case, so there must be some solution. Please refer my code below -

**App.js**

```
import * as React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import DraggableTabsList from "./components/DraggableTabsList";

export default function App() {
  const [tabs, setTabs] = React.useState(
    [...Array(55)].map((_, index) => ({
      id: `tab${index + 1}`,
      label: `Tab ${index + 1}`,
      value: `${index + 1}`,
      content: `Content ${index + 1}`
    }))
  );

  const onDragEnd = (result) => {
    const newTabs = Array.from(tabs);
    const draggedTab = newTabs.splice(result.source.index, 1)[0];
    newTabs.splice(result.destination.index, 0, draggedTab);
    setTabs(newTabs);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <DraggableTabsList onDragEnd={onDragEnd} tabs={tabs} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**/components/DraggableTabsList.jsx**

```
import * as React from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import TabContext from "@mui/lab/TabContext";
import TabList from "@mui/lab/TabList";
import TabPanel from "@mui/lab/TabPanel";
import { DragDropContext, Droppable } from "react-beautiful-dnd";
import DraggableTab from "./DraggableTab";
import Tab from "@mui/material/Tab";
import Stack from "@mui/material/Stack";

export default function DraggableTabsList(props) {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState("1");

  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  const _renderTabList = (droppableProvided) => (
    <TabList
      onChange={handleChange}
      aria-label="Draggable Tabs"
      variant="scrollable"
    >
      {props.tabs.map((tab, index) => {
        const child = <Tab label={tab.label} value={tab.value} key={index} />;

        return (
          <DraggableTab
            label={tab.label}
            value={tab.value}
            index={index}
            key={index}
            child={child}
          />
        );
      })}
      {droppableProvided ? droppableProvided.placeholder : null}
    </TabList>
  );

  const _renderTabListWrappedInDroppable = () => (
    <DragDropContext onDragEnd={props.onDragEnd}>
      <Droppable droppableId="1" direction="horizontal">
        {(droppableProvided) => (
          <div
            ref={droppableProvided.innerRef}
            {...droppableProvided.droppableProps}
          >
            {_renderTabList(droppableProvided)}
          </div>
        )}
      </Droppable>
    </DragDropContext>
  );

  return (
    <Box sx={{ width: "100%", typography: "body1" }}>
      <TabContext value={value}>
        <Box sx={{ borderBottom: 1, borderColor: "divider" }}>
          <Stack direction="column">{_renderTabListWrappedInDroppable()}</Stack>
        </Box>
        {props.tabs.map((tab, index) => (
          <TabPanel value={tab.value} key={index}>
            {tab.content}
          </TabPanel>
        ))}
      </TabContext>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

**components/DraggableTab.jsx**

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Draggable } from "react-beautiful-dnd";

export default function DraggableTab(props) {
  return (
    <Draggable
      draggableId={`${props.index}`}
      index={props.index}
      disableInteractiveElementBlocking
    >
      {(draggableProvided) => (
        <div
          ref={draggableProvided.innerRef}
          {...draggableProvided.draggableProps}
        >
          {React.cloneElement(props.child, {
            ...props,
            ...draggableProvided.dragHandleProps,
            style: { cursor: "inherit" }
          })}
        </div>
      )}
    </Draggable>
  );
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved by - in `/components/DraggableTabsList.jsx` wrap the `Droppable` inside a div container with style `{display:"flex", overflow:"auto"}`. The new code would look like -

```
<div style={{ display: 'flex', overflow: 'auto' }}>
    <Droppable droppableId="1" direction="horizontal">
        {(droppableProvided) => (
            <div
                ref={droppableProvided.innerRef}
                {...droppableProvided.droppableProps}
            >
                {_renderTabList(droppableProvided)}
            </div>
        )}
    </Droppable>
</div>
```

This will make the tabs horizontally draggable through the entire tab list, but the scroll buttons from the MUI TabList will not render.

Codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/mr9y10

Comment: The a11y is a bit funky here. Pressing space to initiate a drag works but the placement afterwards is a bit skewed. It's very clean on the react-beautiful-dnd storybook https://react-beautiful-dnd.netlify.app/?path=/story/single-vertical-list--basic